# Make bottom borders in line according to the lowest content

Tags: html, css, border

I'm developing my homepage using HTML, CSS, JSP and JavaScript, about musical instrument sale and communication of people.

Currently, I'm implementing a site-map for my site's menu configuration chart using `div`, `ul`, `li` and `h` tags. I would like to create bottom borders under the lowermost submenu items (last `li` tags) like in the picture below (see the blue indications). They should have bottom borders in line, adjusted to the lowermost (last) `li` tag.

[image: Bottom borders in line adjusted to the content]

How can I achieve my goal? This is what I have so far:

```css
#sitemap_menu_container {
  width: 980px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid violet;
}


.sitemap_menu {
  width: 150px;
  height: 180px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
}

.sitemap_menu_header1 {
  font-size: 15pt;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
}

.sitemap_menu_header2 {
  font-size: 15pt;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: red;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
}

.sitemap_menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-family: Arial;
  background: url(../images/bullet1.png)no-repeat 0px 50%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="sitemap_menu_container">
  <div class="sitemap_menu">
    <h2 class="sitemap_menu_header1">About</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>P&G introduce</li>
      <li>P&G history</li>
      <li>location</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="sitemap_menu">
    <h2 class="sitemap_menu_header2">Piano goods</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>All kind of piano</li>
      <li>Upright</li>
      <li>Grand</li>
      <li>Electronics</li>
      <li>Synthesizer</li>
      <li>Management Tools</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="sitemap_menu">
    <h2 class="sitemap_menu_header1">Guitar goods</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Acoustic</li>
      <li>Classic</li>
      <li>Electrics</li>
      <li>Ukulele</li>
      <li>Management Tools</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="sitemap_menu">
    <h2 class="sitemap_menu_header2">Community</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Free Board</li>
      <li>Reviews</li>
      <li>Gallery Board</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="sitemap_menu">
    <h2 class="sitemap_menu_header1">Event</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Ongoing Event</li>
      <li>Announcement</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="sitemap_menu">
    <h2 class="sitemap_menu_header2">Help you</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Guide</li>
      <li>Notice</li>
      <li>FAQ</li>
      <li>Q&A</li>
      <li>Sitemap</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do that, you can use flexbox to be more flexible. Indeed, remove the height constraint in `#sitemap_menu_container` and `.sitemap-menu` and add `display: flex` to `#sitemap_menu_container`. Here is the snippet:

```css
#sitemap_menu_container {
  width: 980px;
  border: 1px solid violet;
  display: flex;
}


.sitemap_menu {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
}

.sitemap_menu_header1 {
  font-size: 15pt;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
}

.sitemap_menu_header2 {
  font-size: 15pt;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: red;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
}

.sitemap_menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-family: Arial;
  background: url(../images/bullet1.png)no-repeat 0px 50%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="sitemap_menu_container">
  <div class="sitemap_menu">
    <h2 class="sitemap_menu_header1">About</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>P&G introduce</li>
      <li>P&G history</li>
      <li>location</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="sitemap_menu">
    <h2 class="sitemap_menu_header2">Piano goods</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>All kind of piano</li>
      <li>Upright</li>
      <li>Grand</li>
      <li>Electronics</li>
      <li>Synthesizer</li>
      <li>Management Tools</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="sitemap_menu">
    <h2 class="sitemap_menu_header1">Guitar goods</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Acoustic</li>
      <li>Classic</li>
      <li>Electrics</li>
      <li>Ukulele</li>
      <li>Management Tools</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="sitemap_menu">
    <h2 class="sitemap_menu_header2">Community</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Free Board</li>
      <li>Reviews</li>
      <li>Gallery Board</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="sitemap_menu">
    <h2 class="sitemap_menu_header1">Event</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Ongoing Event</li>
      <li>Announcement</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="sitemap_menu">
    <h2 class="sitemap_menu_header2">Help you</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Guide</li>
      <li>Notice</li>
      <li>FAQ</li>
      <li>Q&A</li>
      <li>Sitemap</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Keep in mind that it's only working in modern browsers: https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox. If you target older borwser, I think you need to use a table.

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you for your feedback. I've tryed it, but I want to make positioning on last li tag content. your snippet's result is implemented unconditionally status in arranged most the greatest contents of <li> tag inside <ul> tag. I'm awkward in writing English. i'm Sorry. anyway, I get many aid due to you. thanks, I'll trying this Constantly.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the below css to give border-bottom to the last `<li>` of your sub-menu

```
.sitemap_menu ul li:last-child{border-bottom:1px solid #000;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<hr>` instead, just adjust the height of the columns

```css
#sitemap_menu_container {
  width: 980px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid violet;
}

.sitemap_menu {
  width: 150px;
  height: 180px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.sitemap_menu_header1 {
  font-size: 15pt;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
}

.sitemap_menu_header2 {
  font-size: 15pt;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: red;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
}

.sitemap_menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-family: Arial;
  background: url(../images/bullet1.png)no-repeat 0px 50%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="sitemap_menu_container">
  <div class="sitemap_menu">
    <h2 class="sitemap_menu_header1">About</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>P&G introduce</li>
      <li>P&G history</li>
      <li>location</li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="sitemap_menu">
    <h2 class="sitemap_menu_header2">Piano goods</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>All kind of piano</li>
      <li>Upright</li>
      <li>Grand</li>
      <li>Electronics</li>
      <li>Synthesizer</li>
      <li>Management Tools</li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="sitemap_menu">
    <h2 class="sitemap_menu_header1">Guitar goods</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Acoustic</li>
      <li>Classic</li>
      <li>Electrics</li>
      <li>Ukulele</li>
      <li>Management Tools</li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="sitemap_menu">
    <h2 class="sitemap_menu_header2">Community</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Free Board</li>
      <li>Reviews</li>
      <li>Gallery Board</li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="sitemap_menu">
    <h2 class="sitemap_menu_header1">Event</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Ongoing Event</li>
      <li>Announcement</li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="sitemap_menu">
    <h2 class="sitemap_menu_header2">Help you</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Guide</li>
      <li>Notice</li>
      <li>FAQ</li>
      <li>Q&A</li>
      <li>Sitemap</li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In this answer the lines are not in line - at least in Chrome. [Richard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44945807/1494454) is the proper solution.